# Add prefix to filter function

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a Way to add a prefix to the filter function so the result looks like this:

```
Prefix Value1
Prefix Value2
Prefix Value3
```

I already tried things like:

```
="Prefix "&FILTER(Data;condition1;condition2)
```

which resulted in just the first value of the filter getting returned with the prefix the rest didn't get returned.

```
Prefix Value1
```

also tried this:

```
=TEXTJOIN("Prefix ";FILTER(Data;condition1;condition2))
```

This resulted in:

```
Prefix ReturnValue1ReturneValue2ReturnValue3
```

so my current workaround is to just Filter in another column and in the column I want the prefix with the filter I just say

```
="Prefix "&B1
="Prefix "&B2
="Prefix "&B3
...
```

This results in about 8000 Cells that need to be recalculated each time something changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the Prefix to the already filtered data you can use ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("Prefix "&FILTER(Q:Q,Q:Q>3))
```

(Obviously, change the filter, it's just an example)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concatenate function or the '&' operator in your filter.

Function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en

```
=FILTER([Range], CONCATENATE("Prefix ", [Range])="filtervalue")

=FILTER([Range], "Prefix " & [Range]="filtervalue")
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX("Prefix "&FILTER(Data; condition1; condition2))
```

example:

```
=INDEX("Prefix "&FILTER(A:C; B:B<>""; C:C<>""))
```

but you can use only FILTER too if you do it like:

```
=FILTER({"Prefix "&A:A\ B:C}; B:B<>""; C:C<>""))
```